# stress of function words in English

Tags: phonology, phonetics

Generally speaking, what are conditions under which function words in English are to be stressed.

I am working on weak/strong/contracted forms in English and the textbook states that `WFs are to be used when the function word is unstressed`

So when is this the case, when not?

Comment: They are contracted whenever possible, and unstressed unless they are being used contrastively (_I didn't give you **a** dollar, I gave you **4** dollars_) or emphatically (_Dr. Eszterhazy is **the** man to see for this ailment_). Which is to say, practically all the time. And sometimes they disappear entirely, like the _have_ in _have got_.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the cases mentioned by Lawler in his comment, coming at the end of a constituent containing more than one word will often require stress and prevent contraction. "Would you like some ice cream?"  "Yes, I'd like sm ice cream" / "Yes, I'd like some" / *"Yes, I'd like sm" / "Yes, I would" / *"Yes, I'd".